# How to assign UrlFetchApp with basic authorization to button?

Tags: google-apps-script, get, basic-authentication, urlfetch, x-forwarded-for

I created function in Google Apps Script, that works well when I run it in Google Apps Script. Output data returns to Google Sheets.

```
function testFunction11() {
  var rng = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var encodedAuthInformation = Utilities.base64Encode("username:key");
  var headers = {"Authorization" : "Basic " + encodedAuthInformation};
  var params = {
    'method': 'GET',
    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
    'headers': headers
  };
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.apiservice.com/api/v1/xxx?fields=somefields", params);
  Logger.log(res.getContentText());
  rng.setValue(res);
}
```

Output in cell:

```
[
  {
    "id": xxx,
    "createdDate": "2019-02-01T04:54:00Z",
    "reference": "XXX"
  },
etc
```

Then I assign script to button, 'testFunction11'.
And when I click button, it returns

```
{
  "message": "An error has occurred."
}
```

It looks like response from API server.

My only hypothesis is that google sheet's button adds some headers, User-Agent or content-type to request, which not allowed in API server. And after some search, I guess I can't reassign User-Agent in request. Is that something right or I do it wrong?

**EDIT 1:**

Headers for each case `console.log(UrlFetchApp.getRequest(url, params))`:
When clicking button in spreadsheet:

```
{headers={Authorization=Basic XXXXXXXXQVU6MWVhODlmZmFkN2U3NGNjOGJkOTc1YTE1ZjVhNTE3MzE=, X-Forwarded-For=178.xx.my.ip}, method=get, payload=, followRedirects=true, validateHttpsCertificates=true, useIntranet=false, contentType=null, url=https://api.apisite.com/api/v1/SalesOrders?fields=Id,Createddate,Reference&where=Createddate%3E2019-02-01T00:00:00Z}
```

And for script:

```
{headers={Authorization=Basic XXXXXXXXQVU6MWVhODlmZmFkN2U3NGNjOGJkOTc1YTE1ZjVhNTE3MzE=}, method=get, payload=, followRedirects=true, validateHttpsCertificates=true, useIntranet=false, contentType=null, url=https://api.apisite.com/api/v1/SalesOrders?fields=Id,Createddate,Reference&where=Createddate%3E2019-02-01T00:00:00Z}
```

So the button only adds `X-Forwarded-For`.

When I tried manually add `X-Forwarded-For: 'unknown'` there are error like this

```
There are attribute with impossible value: Header:X-Forwarded-For
```

Text of error in russian, so sorry for maybe not accurate translating. It's fun, because when I added `Test: unknown` in same way, there are no error, but obviously not working. Looks like google don't allow to change this value.

Will try different headers in postman and maybe confirm that this header is the cause of the error. Thank you @TheMaster

**EDIT 2:**

I tried different headers via Postman. So, result is when I add to headers `X-Forwarded-For` key with any value, it return `"message": "An error has occurred."`
When I don't add this key, it works well.

So, the question is any way to disable adding this header via Google Apps Script. It seems like not.

Comment: Show your headers in each case: `console.log(UrlFetchApp.getRequest(url, params))`

Comment: @TheMaster and for script: `{headers={Authorization=Basic XXXXXXXXQVU6MWVhODlmZmFkN2U3NGNjOGJkOTc1YTE1ZjVhNTE3MzE=}, method=get, payload=, followRedirects=true, validateHttpsCertificates=true, useIntranet=false, contentType=null, url=https://api.apisite.com/api/v1/SalesOrders?fields=Id,Createddate,Reference&where=Createddate%3E2019-02-01T00:00:00Z}`

Comment: So the button only adds a `X-Forwarded-For` your ip address header? And that causes your api to fail?

Comment: Oh, looks like this. But when I getting data from api via browser (same ip), it works well.

Comment: Try manually adding the header in your script and run from script editor. `X-Forwarded-For: 'unknown'`

Comment: @TheMaster when I added this to headers, there are error on top of page with red background : `There are attribute with impossible value: Header:X-Forwarded-For ` Actually this text of error is on russian, so sorry for maybe not accurate translating

Comment: It's fun, because when I added `Test: unknown` in same way, there are no error, but obviously not working. Looks like google don't allow to change this value.

Comment: [Edit] your question with all these information in the comments for wider audience. If this header is the problem, then there's probably nothing you can do to fix it, AFAIK.  But it's also possible that the error is somewhere else. Try setting these headers in curl/postman/other api testers and confirm that this header is the cause of the error.

Comment: @TheMaster thank you for help! Will edit question and try different headers in postman shortly.

Comment: @imnotyourguru I proposed a workaround. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- In your situation, when `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` is run from a button on Spreadsheet, `X-Forwarded-For` is automatically added to the header.
- By added `X-Forwarded-For` to the header, the error of `An error has occurred.` occurs.
- On the other hand, `X-Forwarded-For` is not used in the header, no error occurs.

If my understanding is correct, how about this workaround? I think that there might be several workarounds. So please think of this as just one of them. In this workaround, Web Apps is used as a wrapper function.

#### Sample script:

At first, please copy and paste the following script. And please set `testFunction11()` to the button. When `testFunction11()` is run, `testFunction11()` requests to Web Apps (`doGet()`), and Web Apps requests to `https://api.apiservice.com/api/v1/xxx?fields=somefields`. By this, `X-Forwarded-For` is not used to the header of request. Then, the result of Web Apps is returned and put the value to the spreadsheet. **Please deploy Web Apps, before you run the script.**

```
function testFunction11() {
  var rng = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  var params = {method: "get", headers: {Authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  Logger.log(res.getContentText());
  rng.setValue(res);
}

function doGet() {
  var url = "https://api.apiservice.com/api/v1/xxx?fields=somefields";
  var encodedAuthInformation = Utilities.base64Encode("username:key");
  var headers = {"Authorization" : "Basic " + encodedAuthInformation};
  var params = {
    'method': 'GET',
    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
    'headers': headers
  };
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(res.getContentText());
}
```

#### Deploy Web Apps:

Before you run this script, please deploy Web Apps.

- On the Script Editor
- Publish -> Deploy as Web App

  1. Create new Project version
  2. At "Execute the app a"s, select "Me"
  3. At "Who has access to the app",

     - if the function is used by only you, select "Only myself".
     - if the function is used by several users, select "Anyone".
  4. Click "Deploy"
  5. Copy "Current web app URL"
  6. Click "OK"

#### Note:

- **When you modified the script, please redeploy Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to Web Apps.** This is an important point.
- This is a simple sample script. So please modify to your situation.

#### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)

Comment: thank you! in `var params = {method: "get", headers: {Authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};` Bearer should be email of my google account? If so, there are error `Your input contains more than the maximum of 50000 characters in a single cell.` If I keep on `Bearer` there are error: `401. <HTML> <HEAD> <TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE> </HEAD> <BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000"> <H1>Unauthorized</H1> <H2>Error 401</H2> </BODY> </HTML> `

Comment: Actually it works after I changed 'Who has access to the app:' to 'Anyone, even anonymous'. Thank you so much! One question, cause I'm a bit confused in code. Can I change name of function 'doGet'? Because I would like to have multiple buttons for different requests.

Comment: I think you should also provide your github "Taking advantage of web-apps" as reference in all your web-app answers :) Nice workaround.

Comment: @imnotyourguru Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. ``doGet`` is used for the method of GET request. So the function name cannot be changed. But if you want to run several functions by GET request, please use the query parameters. By using the query parameters, several functions can be called from ``doGet``.

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for your comment. I added it.

Answer (score 3):

For future searches on this topic: I had an issue with the exact same error message, where I was using `UrlFetchApp#getRequest` as a utility to generate a request object, then sending it with `UrlFetchApp#fetchAll`.

The solution was to avoid using `getRequest` and instead build the request by myself *without using any `X-Forwarded-For` header*, which allowed the request to complete successfully.

I can't find any documentation to support this, but I would speculate that the following issue occurred: when Google injects the `X-Forwarded-For` header before making a request, the IP it injects depends on the context the script gets executed in. I think Google validates that if that header is set manually, then the IP address needs to match either their GAS proxy's IP or the user's browser IP; which one to use seems to change depending on the context the script is executed in.