# Attribute provided with invalid value in Google Apps Script

Tags: http, google-apps-script, x-forwarded-for

### Problem

- I want to communicate with api while changing IP address, because the server restricts IP address. So, I add **X-Forwarded-For** header with UrlFetchApp. However, I get an error "**Attribute provided with invalid value: Header:X-Forwarded-For**
  "

### Question

- How can I solve this problem? Or is there another way?

```
function myFetch() {

  var url = "https://XXXXXXXXX"

  var options = { method: "GET" };
  options.headers = {
    Authorization: "Bearer " + MY_TOKEN,
    "X-Forwarded-For": "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"
  };

  var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var json = resp.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);

  return data;
}
```

### Tried → Error

- Tried : cURL request.
  →Success : I can change IP address, and get data.

```
    curl -X GET \
      https://XXXXXXXXX \
      -H 'Authorization: Bearer MY_TOKEN' \
      -H 'X-Forwarded-For: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX' \
```

- Tried : Delete X-Forwarded-For header.
  →Error : "**API key does not allow access from IP XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX**"
- Tried : I also add Host header. 
  →Error : "**Attribute provided with invalid value: Header:Host**".

Does anybody have a solution for my problem?
Best regards,

Comment: In your situation, how do you want to execute your script? Can you provide several executing methods that you can use? Because I thought that it is required to think of the solution and workaround for each executing method.

Comment: If you use a button to click and execute, X-Forwaded is automatically added. See [Tanaike's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54622357) and [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D+X-Forwarded-For)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I want to execute with time-driven trigger.

Comment: Some HTTP Request Headers are internally managed by App Script and cannot be overridden from a `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` call. `X-Forwarded-For` appears to be one of those headers. You can try leveraging an intermediary service to handle that request such as a Google Cloud Function.

Comment: Ok, I'll do this GCF. I decided thx.

Comment: I have created a feature request here : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/267096387. Go +1 it